# Jersey 3.0.1 - Cannot get MediaType from FormDataBodyPart

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-3.0

i have updated my project dependencies in gradle from
compile("org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:2.3.2") to
compile("org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:3.0.1")

And i get the following error, tried to inspect the code to see if would point me into the direction of getting the MediaType from FormDataBodyPart but was not able to figure it out, where should i get the Mediatype in Jersey 3?

```
private boolean isFileChecksOk(FormDataContentDisposition fileDisposition, FormDataBodyPart body, byte[] bytes) {

        boolean mediaTypeOk = body.getMediaType().getSubtype().equalsIgnoreCase(excelMediaType);
        ...
        ...    

}

error: cannot access MediaType
        boolean mediaTypeOk = body.getMediaType().getSubtype().equalsIgnoreCase(excelMediaType);
                                               ^
  class file for jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType not found
```

build.gradle dependencies:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.4.3")
    }
}
```

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")

    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310")
    compile("com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:6.2.4")

    compile("org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:3.0.1")
    compile("net.java.dev.msv:msv-core:2013.6.1")
    compile("com.impossibl.pgjdbc-ng:pgjdbc-ng:0.8.6")
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.12.0')
    compile('commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0')
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-compress:1.20')
    compile('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.2')
    compile('org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:3.1.0')
    compile('com.monitorjbl:xlsx-streamer:2.1.0')
    compile('com.zaxxer:HikariCP')
    compile("org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.3.2"){
        exclude group: 'com.zaxxer', module: 'HikariCP-java7'
    }
    compile('no.applikativ:twistgrid-builder:2.0.0')
    compile('org.apache.tika:tika-parsers:1.25')
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")

    slowtestCompile("org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:2.0.3")    slowtestCompile("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-console-standalone:1.7.0")


}
```

TIA

Comment: You have shown that you have upgraded _one_ Jersey dependency. Does this mean that you have upgrade _all_ your Jersey dependencies? Can you please post all you dependencies? Also have you cleaned your project?

Comment: it seems i only have one Jersey dependency, not sure if its injected/transitional from other package, i could use insights to check, but i dont seem to have the core.

Comment: it seems more like a change in API but i could not find any migration guide for it.

Comment: `spring-boot-starter-jersey` (pulls in all Jersey deps) still uses Jersey 2.x AFAIK. Why do you need multipart 3.0?

Comment: oh yes you are totally right i did not saw that. than i can try to see if spring-boot-starter-jersey includes the media multipart, if so, than i will just update spring-boot. Thats the correct approach right?

Comment: No it will not include multipart. See what version that starter uses and use the same multipart version.

Comment: yes it has to follow the spring boot version. I'm doing some dependencies upgrade as part of security updates, but i guess i have to follow the boot versioning, its more maintainable. Thanks a lot, i will look into your blog :) Thanks!